# Using AdMob with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

How can I integrate [AdMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/) with unity ? I want to call Ad's from code, for example when player dead. I searched for tuts but I can't find anything for newest android sdk. Can I write it in c# ?

Comment: https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob Admob Unity Plugin provides a way to integrate admob ads in Unity3D Game and u3d app. You can use it for Unity iOS and Android App with the same c# or js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prime31 plugin, it makes the process dead simple. With two lines of code you can get a banner up and running.

http://prime31.com/

Answer (score 0):

Download the Google official AdMob Plugin from here - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins

And documentation here - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity